# Print created menu directly in a page

Tags: 7

I have created a menu like france menu. I just want to print it using print_r statement. Is it possible? I know menu block is there. But i don't wanna use it.

Comment: ????? huh ?????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-your-custom-menu-name');
print_r (theme('links__menu_your_custom_menu_name', array('links' => $menu)));
```

Source: [How to print a menu in Drupal 7 ?](http://drupal.org/node/1043018#comment-4248730) and the next comment is also useful: p[rinting custom secondary menu when the user is logged out](http://drupal.org/node/1043018#comment-4570894).

Changelog for Drupal 7: [Use #theme='links_*MODULE' or #theme='links*_MODULE_EXTRA_CONTEXT' when adding links to a render array](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#theme_links_with_context).

**Edit:** new version using [`menu_tree()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7)

```
$menu = menu_tree('main-menu');
$menuhtml = drupal_render($menu);
print_r($menuhtml);
```

Comment: it works fine . But it prints only parents.. how can i print the children's also?

Comment: Try to put the option "expanded" on the parents (in the menu's configuration), this will print all the children.

Comment: - i have done that. still its not printing.

Comment: I updated my answer using `menu_tree`. I tested this on my site and if the parent menu is expanded it will display its children.